# vite-plugin-federation doesn't load the styles of my components

Tags: webpack, tailwind-css, vite, federation

When I'm loading my components on my host app, the componnet loads with no css, I'm using Vite + Vue with tailwind, does anyone know how to load those styles?

This is my vite.conf.ts:

```js
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";


export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 8000,
  },
  build: {
    target: ["chrome101", "edge89", "firefox89", "safari15"],
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    federation({
      name: "myLib",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      // Modules to expose
      exposes: {
        "./Counter": "./src/components/Counter.vue",
        "./Controller": "./src/controller.ts",
      },
      shared: ["vue", "css"],
    }),
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-> shared: ["vue", "tailwindcss"]

-> build: {
target: 'esnext',
minify: false,
cssCodeSplit: false
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

try add **cssCodeSplit:false**, for example:

```
...
build: { 
     target: 'esnext', 
     minify: false, 
     cssCodeSplit: false
   }
```